# Reset or restore previous installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, restore

I'm new to `Ubuntu` and I have a `Windows 8.1` and `Ubuntu 14.04` in my machine and I want to restore or reset my Ubuntu. How can I have a New Ubuntu like fresh installation? If there's no way on how to do that then how can I uninstall it from `dual boot` and reinstall it? I hope it won't affect the boot process on my machine.

Comment: If it's a separate partition, just reinstall to the same partition, and be sure to check the "Format" checkbox.  It will install GRUB again, allowing you to dual-boot.  If it's WUBI, I have no idea; I guess uninstall from windows and reinstall.

Comment: So I need to boot it again from my `Live CD`? and then format the partition of my Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best way I know.  Just use the same partition.  EDIT:  It's the same as the initial install.

Comment: And 100% sure? It won't affect my Windows 8.1?

Comment: Nothing is ever 100%, but if it worked the first time, it will work the same, assuming you use the same partition.  If you don't, it will, by default, try to keep both Windows and the old Ubuntu.  So, pay attention, and don't install alongside the existing two.

Comment: I need to choose `something else` right? I'm just a novice sir so pardon for noob questions

Comment: Yes.  Actually, I always choose something else.  I also like to write down the sizes of all partitions to confirm I get the right one.

Comment: Okay Sir! Will do it right now. Hoping for good though. Restarting . . .

Answer (score 1):

When booting with the Live CD there's an option there that **Erase Ubuntu installation and reinstall** and that solved my problem.